# Python: Why assigning list values inline returns a list of "None" elements?

Tags: python, list

I'm still new to Python, and I've been making a small function that reverses a list of lists, both the original list and the lists inside. This is my code:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    L.reverse()
    L = [i.reverse() for i in L]
```

Now this code works perfectly, but if I do a small change and rearrange the lines like this:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    L = [i.reverse() for i in L]
    L.reverse()
```

suddenly it stops working! It only reverses the internal lists but not the original one. Putting some debugging print() statements inside, I can see the first code reverses the original list after the first line and it's printed, but the second code actually prints a list containing 'None' as elements after reversing the list. Can anyone please explain why this behavior and what is the difference between the two codes?

Comment: You’re misusing list comprehensions. Assigning to `L` doesn’t change whatever was passed into the function and `reverse()` doesn’t return anything. Should be `for i in L: i.reverse()`

Comment: But the code does work. How am I misusing it if it works?

Comment: You forgot to `return L` at the end of both functions

Comment: *“How am I misusing it if it works?”* `5 * [print("Hello, world")]` prints “Hello world”. Would you consider it a correct use of multiplication, even if that’s what you intended to print?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't want to return anything. It just mutates the list without returning it. But let's say I return L, still the second code doesn't work and it changes its behavior once more, so it reverses only the outer list but not the lists inside. So now I have without return the inner lists get reversed but not the outer, with return, the opposite happens! Does that make sense?

Comment: @Ryan I don't mean this of course. I have already seen that usage on different answers here before using it, so I figured it's a normal usage not a bad one.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdel-Mon'em mutating/assigning a parameter is a bad idea, in general.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez So `random.shuffle` is bad?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yes, as programming practice I know it's bad, but I'm still new so I'm trying out, for my knowledge, not for a real project. This question is an exercise for a course I'm currently taking.

Comment: Using a mutator method in a list comprehension is bad. List comprehensions are functional programming constructs. You shouldn't be using them to effect a state change. What's worse, as you are discovering, mutator methods on lists return `None` so it isn't doing what you are trying to do.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga and Ryan thank you for explaining!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `reverse()` function reverses a list in-place and returns `None`, that explains the weird behavior. A correct implementation would be:

```
def deep_reverse(L):
  ans = [i[::-1] for i in L]
  ans.reverse()
  return ans
```

Also, it's a bad idea to reassign and/or mutate a parameter to a function, it can lead to unexpected results. Sometimes functions in the standard library do it for efficiency reasons (for example, `sort()` and `reverse()`), that's ok - but it can lead to confusions, like the one you just experienced. Your code doesn't have to be written in that fashion unless strictly necessary.

Comment: or `reversed(i)`, which may be more readable than the slicing method

Comment: @ÓscarLópez ah fair enough. `list(reversed(i))` would do it in that case, but that starts to look less readable than slicing...

Answer (score 1):

Your first `deep_reverse` function reassigned `L`, but it is not a global parameter and is not returned in your function.  Hence this variable is lost.  HOWEVER, you are mutating the list in place, hence the modifications remain which is why it still works!  Your original function is equivalent to the following (note there is no final assignment):

```
def deep_reverse(L):
    L.reverse()
    [i.reverse() for i in L]
```

This should probably be written using a for-loop:

```
def deep_reverse_2(L):
    L.reverse()
    for i in L:
        i.reverse()

L = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]
deep_reverse_2(L)
>>> L
[[4, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

The second function does not work because you reassign `L` inside the function (it is now local to the function and not the same `L` variable you passed in to the function). They would have different memory locations if you checked using `id`.  Given that nothing is returned, this new `L` list is lost, as are the modifications made to it.

Comment: Thank you. But as I explained, I want the code to reverse both the outer list, and the lists inside. Your code reverses the inside elements only. Edit: actually my first deep_reverse() function does work, the second one is the one I had problems with.

Comment: Thank you! Now it makes sense!

Comment: Check this SO question for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument